# $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow S^n$ is a submersion

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, projective-space, spheres, diffeomorphism

I have to solve this one:

> "Prove that the application $\psi:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow S^n$, $x\mapsto\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ is a submersion".

My idea is to use that "composition of submersion is a submersion", given the diagram, with $\psi=\pi^{-1}\circ f$

\begin{array}{ccc}
 & \psi & \\
\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\} & \rightarrow & S^n \\
f \searrow & & \swarrow \pi \\
 & \mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R}) & 
\end{array}

I proved that $f$ is a submersion. Moreover I know that $\pi$ is a local diffeomprphism, so $\pi_{*p}:T_p S^n\rightarrow T_{\pi(p)}\mathbb{P}^n(R)$ is a isomorphism for all $p\in S^n$ and so it is injective and surjective. In conclusion $\pi$ is an immersion and a submersion.

Now the thing is: can I say that $\pi^{-1}$ is a submersion too? Can I say that $\pi^{-1}$ is a local diffeomorphism?

Thank you so much

Comment: Isn't the point of a diffeomorphism that the inverse is also a diffeomorphism?

Comment: Yes that's it, but it seemed so easy that I couldn't believe it! Thank you